# Capturing Typescript mapping function result type for type-safe Mappers

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to describe strong typesafe constraints around a JSON mapping function.
This function takes an object as first parameter and returns a mapped representation of this object using mapping functions passed as second parameter.

As a consumer point of view, something like this contract :

```
let mappedResult = mapJson(
    // Standard plain object literal coming, most of the time from serverside, generally described by an interface
    // Let's call this type SRC
    { date: "2018-10-04T00:00:00+0200", date2: 1538604000000, aString: "Hello%20World", idempotentValue: "foo" },
    // Applying some mapping functions to convert input values above to a different type representation. Let's call this type MAPPING.
    // Rules are :
    // - Keys should be a subset of SRC's keys
    // - Values should be functions taking SRC[key] and returning a new type NEW_TYPE[key] we want to capture in order to reference it in mapJson()'s result type
    { date: Date.parse, date2: (ts: number) => new Date(ts), aString: unescape }
); // Result type should be something like {[key in SRC]: RESULT[key] ... and SRC[key] if undefined}
// Expecting to get mappedResult = { date: Date.parse("2018-10-04T00:00:00+0200"), date2: new Date(1538604000000), aString: unescape("Hello%20World"), idempotentValue: "foo" }
// Meaning that expected type would be { date: number, date2: Date, aString: string, idempotentValue: string }
```

I met multiple complexities :

1. Capturing mapping function return types by key
2. Using this captured type in result ... and falling back on SRC type if not found in NEW_TYPE (something like union types but not exactly that)

I tried something like this but I cannot even have 1/ working (I know 2/ shouldn't work in that case) as mapJson() result value types are of type `any` :

```
function mapJson<
    SRC extends object,
    // That's a 'capture-only' type definition here, used as a placeholder for mappings' return types
    CAPTURED_TARGET_MAPPINGS_TYPES extends {[ATTR in keyof SRC]?: CAPTURED_TARGET_MAPPINGS_TYPES[ATTR]} ,
    TARGET_MAPPINGS extends {[ATTR in keyof SRC]?: (value: SRC[ATTR], obj?: SRC) => CAPTURED_TARGET_MAPPINGS_TYPES[ATTR]}
>(src: SRC, mappings: TARGET_MAPPINGS): {[ATTR in keyof SRC]: CAPTURED_TARGET_MAPPINGS_TYPES[ATTR]} {

    // implementation here... not the purpose of this question :-)
}
```

My purpose is to really have a strong typesafe function signature (both for inputs & outputs) and I'm wondering if Typescript 3.1 can currently handle this case.

If you have some spare time to help, I would be grateful :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use the extra `CAPTURED_TARGET_MAPPINGS_TYPES` for the mapping types, I would just use a conditional type to get the return type of the function (or the original type if no type mapping is specified, as for `idempotentValue`)

```
type FunctionMap<SRC> = {[ATTR in keyof SRC]?: (value: SRC[ATTR], obj?: SRC) => any}
type MappedReturnType<SRC,TARGET_MAPPINGS extends FunctionMap<SRC>> ={
    [ATTR in keyof SRC]:   [TARGET_MAPPINGS[ATTR]] extends [undefined]   ? SRC[ATTR]  : ReturnType<Extract<TARGET_MAPPINGS[ATTR], Function>> 
}

function mapJson<
    SRC,
    TARGET_MAPPINGS extends FunctionMap<SRC>
>(src: SRC, mappings: TARGET_MAPPINGS):  MappedReturnType<SRC, TARGET_MAPPINGS>{

  return null as any;
    // implementation here... not the purpose of this question :-)
}

let mappedResult = mapJson(
  // Standard plain object literal coming, most of the time from serverside, generally described by an interface
  // Let's call this type SRC
  { date: "2018-10-04T00:00:00+0200", date2: 1538604000000, aString: "Hello%20World", idempotentValue: "foo" },
  // Applying some mapping aimed at converting input values above and change their type representation. Let's call this type MAPPING.
  // Rules are :
  // - Keys should be a subset of SRC's keys
  // - Values should be function taking SRC[key] and returning a new type NEW_TYPE[key] we want to capture in order to reference it in mapJson()'s result type
  { date: Date.parse, date2: (ts: number) => new Date(ts), aString: unescape }
); 

let s = mappedResult.idempotentValue // string
let s2 = mappedResult.date2//Date
let s3 = mappedResult.date // number
```

This should work as far back as 2.8, not sure what version you are currently on.

Comment: Thank you very much ! You both solved 1/ and 2/ that's great ! :-) #thumbUp

Comment: FYI, to improve a bit readability, I replaced "[TARGET_MAPPINGS[ATTR]] extends [undefined]" by "ATTR extends keyof TARGET_MAPPINGS" + swapped conditions (as this constraints returns the opposite boolean than yours)

Comment: I went a bit further, in order to support "computed" properties in target mappings, and hit a strange type inference limitation. Spotted it in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682862/typescript-infered-type-sometimes-resolved-to-any-on-function-return-type if you wanna help ;-)