# Typescript infered type sometimes resolved to any on function return type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to describe strong typesafe constraints around a JSON mapping function. This function takes an object as first parameter and returns a mapped representation of this object using mapping functions passed as second parameter.

As a consumer point of view, something like this contract :

```
let mappedResult = mapJson(
    // Standard plain object literal coming, most of the time from serverside, generally described by an interface
    // Let's call this type SRC
    { date: "2018-10-04T00:00:00+0200", date2: 1538604000000, aString: "Hello%20World", idempotentValue: "foo" },
    // Applying some mapping aimed at converting input values above and change their type representation
    // Rules are :
    // - Keys should be a subset of SRC's keys, except for "new" computed keys
    // - Values should be function taking SRC[key] and returning a new type NEW_TYPE[key] we want to capture in
    // order to reference it in mapJson()'s result type
    // Let's call this type TARGET_MAPPINGS
    { date: Date.parse, date2: (ts: number) => new Date(ts), aString: unescape, computed: (_, obj) => `${obj?`${obj.aString}__${obj.idempotentValue}`:''}` }
); 
// Result type (NEW_TYPE) should be a map with its keys being the union of SRC keys and TARGET_MAPPINGS keys with following rules :
// - If key exists only in SRC, then NEW_TYPE[key] = SRC[key}
// - Otherwise (key existing in TARGET_MAPPINGS), then NEW_TYPE[key] = ResultType<TARGET_MAPPINGS[key]>  
// In this example, expecting 
//   mappedResult = { date: Date.parse("2018-10-04T00:00:00+0200"), date2: new Date(1538604000000), aString: unescape("Hello%20World"), idempotentValue: "foo", computed: "Hello%20World__foo" }
// ..  meaning that expected type would be { date: number, date2: Date, aString: string, idempotentValue: string, computed: string }
```

With some help (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640888/capturing-typescript-mapping-function-result-type-for-type-safe-mappers/52641402#52641402)) I managed to get it mostly working with following types :

```
type ExtractField<ATTR, T, FALLBACK> = ATTR extends keyof T ? T[ATTR] : FALLBACK;
type FunctionMap<SRC> = {
    [ATTR in string]: (value: ExtractField<ATTR, SRC, never>, obj?: SRC) => any
}
type MappedReturnType<SRC, TARGET_MAPPINGS extends FunctionMap<SRC>> = {
    [ATTR in (keyof TARGET_MAPPINGS | keyof SRC)]:
        ATTR extends keyof TARGET_MAPPINGS ? ReturnType<Extract<TARGET_MAPPINGS[ATTR], Function>> : ExtractField<ATTR, SRC, never>
}

export function mapJson<
    SRC extends object,
    TARGET_MAPPINGS extends FunctionMap<SRC>
>(src: SRC, mappings: TARGET_MAPPINGS): MappedReturnType<SRC, TARGET_MAPPINGS> {
    // impl .. not the point of the question
}
```

Everything looks good except "computed" property case which is resolved to type `any` (instead of `string`)

```
let mappedResult = mapJson(
    { date: "2018-10-04T00:00:00+0200", date2: 1538604000000, aString: "Hello%20World", idempotentValue: "foo" },
    { date: Date.parse, date2: (ts: number) => new Date(ts), aString: unescape, computed: (_, obj) => `${obj?`${obj.aString}__${obj.idempotentValue}`:''}` }
);

let v1 = mappedResult.date; // number, expected
let v2 = mappedResult.date2; // Date, expected
let v3 = mappedResult.aString; // string, expected
let v4 = mappedResult.idempotentValue; // string, expected
let v5 = mappedResult.computed; // any, NOT expected (expectation was string here !)
```

I guess this is related to `infer` type resolution, but I don't really see why this works for properties both existing in `SRC` & `TARGET_MAPPINGS` (`date`, `date2` & `string`) and not on properties existing only in `TARGET_MAPPINGS`.

May I have spotted a bug ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `(ts: number) => new Date(ts)` argument type inference seems to be broken as well..

Comment: That's correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FunctionMap` is not doing at all what you intend.  TypeScript doesn't support mapped types with `string` as the constraint type and different property types depending on the actual string.  If you try to declare such a mapped type, the compiler turns it into a type with a string index signature and just replaces all occurrences of the key variable with `string`, i.e.:

```
type FunctionMap<SRC> = {
    [ATTR: string]: (value: ExtractField<string, SRC, never>, obj?: SRC) => any
}
```

Now, since `string` doesn't extend `keyof SRC` for the `SRC` types you are using, the type of the `value` parameter is always `never`.  Then, when the type of the `computed` property of `MappedReturnType<SRC, TARGET_MAPPINGS>` is evaluated, evaluation of `ReturnType<Extract<TARGET_MAPPINGS[ATTR], Function>>` fails because `Extract<TARGET_MAPPINGS[ATTR], Function>` is `(value: never: obj?: SRC) => any`, and the `never` isn't compatible with the constraint `(...args: any[]) => any` of `ReturnType`.  <s>The compiler recovers from the failure by changing the type to `any`; it's a bug that the compiler doesn't report an error.  [Issue 25673](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25673) has the same root cause, so we should probably add this case on to that issue rather than filing a new one.</s>  Edit: On second thought, I think this has nothing to do with issue 25673 and the conditional type in `ReturnType` is just simplifying to its else case, `any`.

I tried to find an alternative solution to your original problem, and I was unable to get TypeScript to infer the proper types without breaking the map into two maps, one for original properties and one for computed properties.  Even apart from the problem described above, using `never` as the type of the `value` parameter for a computed property is unsound because you do pass a value for that parameter, presumably `undefined`.  With a single map, I couldn't find a way to get TypeScript to infer that `value` is `SRC[ATTR]` for original properties and `undefined` for all other property names.  Here is what I came up with:

```
type FieldMap<SRC> = {
    [ATTR in keyof SRC]?: (value: SRC[ATTR], obj: SRC) => any
};
type ComputedMap<SRC> = {
    [ATTR in keyof SRC]?: never
} & {
    [ATTR: string]: (value: undefined, obj: SRC) => any
};
type MappedReturnType<SRC, FM extends FieldMap<SRC>, CM extends ComputedMap<SRC>> = {
    [ATTR in keyof CM]: ReturnType<CM[ATTR]>
} & {
    [ATTR in keyof SRC]: ATTR extends keyof FM
        ? FM[ATTR] extends (value: SRC[ATTR], obj: SRC) => infer R ? R : SRC[ATTR]
        : SRC[ATTR]
}

export function mapJson<
    SRC extends object, FM extends FieldMap<SRC>, CM extends ComputedMap<SRC>
>(src: SRC, fieldMap: FM, computedMap: CM): MappedReturnType<SRC, FM, CM> {
    // impl .. not the point of the question
    return undefined!;
}

let mappedResult = mapJson(
    { date: "2018-10-04T00:00:00+0200", date2: 1538604000000, aString: "Hello%20World", idempotentValue: "foo" },
    // Without `: number`, `ts` is inferred as any:
    // probably https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24694.
    { date: Date.parse, date2: (ts: number) => new Date(ts), aString: unescape},
    {computed: (_, obj) => `${obj?`${obj.aString}__${obj.idempotentValue}`:''}` }
);

let v1 = mappedResult.date; // number, expected
let v2 = mappedResult.date2; // Date, expected
let v3 = mappedResult.aString; // string, expected
let v4 = mappedResult.idempotentValue; // string, expected
let v5 = mappedResult.computed; // string, expected
```

Note that the contextual typing of the parameters of field mapping functions still isn't working.  I believe that's due to [this TypeScript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24694) and I suggest you vote for the issue.