# how do I map (translate) a tuple to another tuple in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I'm trying to map a tuple to another tuple based on a name map and get a strongly typed tuple as the result.

In some cases a single element from the source tuple may map into multiple elements in the result. Also, the source tuple may have variable length.

this is what I have for now:

```
const t1 = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
const nameMap = {
    "a": [],
    "b": ["j"],
    "c": ["k", "l"],
} as const;
const t2 = t1.reduce<string[]>((acc, e) => {
    acc.push(...nameMap[e]);
    return acc;
    }, []);
```

However, "t2" is an array here, not a strongly typed tuple. How do I get t2 to be a strongly typed tuple (["j", "k", "l"] in this case)?

(order does not matter)

Comment: [a similar question I asked about objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78036938/23458818), for reference

Comment: Which question are you asking, the `map` or the `reduce`? They are certainly different, and we should really [focus on just one for this to be suitable for Stack Overflow]((https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/511366)).  Once you [edit] to remove one of those, the other can be given a strong typing from the caller's side, but the implementation will need to use type assertions or other type loosening because the compiler is unable to see how `map` or `reduce` behave on tuples (see [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66091730/2887218)).  How shall we proceed?

Comment: @jcalz Hey, I edited the question. We're doing only the reduce one now

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wReBxW) meet your needs? Again, you can't get the compiler to understand that the implementaton of `mapNames()` satisfies its call signature (meaning type assertions or `any` or something are needed inside the function), but for callers it's strongly typed. If it meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, this is good. Thanks!

You can write this as an answer and I'll mark the question as solved

Comment: @jcalz One minor question though. Can we make it so that nameMap can be partial, and if there is no coresponding entry in the name map, value from the source is used? [I tried here](https://tsplay.dev/mbrEom) but couldn't get it to work

Comment: That's a followup question and out of scope here. It really belongs in its own question post, if you want someone to work on it.  You could maybe do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/mpo0pN) but if you want to discuss further, please open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you'll need to write a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) that walks through the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of the input array and maps them to another array using the name mapper, and builds up an output by concatenating these arrays.

For example, here's a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) called `MapNames<T, M>` which takes an input tuple `T` and a mapping type `M` that converts the elements of `T` into a new array:

```
type MapNames<
    T extends readonly string[],
    M extends Record<T[number], readonly any[]>,
    A extends any[] = []
> = T extends readonly [
    infer F extends keyof M,
    ... infer R extends readonly string[]
] ? MapNames<R, M, [...A, ...M[F]]> : A
```

It uses [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to manipulate both the input and output tuples.  Note that the third type parameter `A` is the *accumulator* and its use makes it tail-recursive and therefore amenable to fairly long input tuples. We break the input tuple `T` into the first element `F` and the rest of the elements `R`.  Then `F` is a key of the mapping type `F`, and we concatenate the array `M[F]` to the end of the accumulator, and recurse.

Then you can write a generic `mapNames()` function that takes inputs of types  `T` and an `M` and returns a `MapNames<T, M>`:

```
function mapNames<
    const T extends readonly string[],
    const M extends Record<T[number], readonly any[]>
>(t: T, m: M): MapNames<T, M> {
    return t.reduce<string[]>((acc, e) => {
        acc.push(...(m as any)[e]);
        return acc;
    }, []) as any;
}
```

This function is implemented the same way as your example, although there's no way for the compiler to understand that the implementation works for such a complicated recursive conditional generic type. So we have to loosen type safety inside the function via [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), or something like it.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const t1 = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
const nameMap = {
    "a": [],
    "b": ["j"],
    "c": ["k", "l"],
} as const;
const t2 = mapNames(t1, nameMap);
//    ^? const t2: ["j", "k", "l"]
console.log(t2); // ["j", "k", "l"]
```

Looks good. The type of `t2` matches the actual value at runtime.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAWQIZQHJILYwM4B5RyFwAqcMAHmDAHYAm2cATjErQPbUA2Ec2YjAS2oBzANoBdADQEiCMpRr04AJRgBjNo1q5io6gFcMAIxiMpTFuy48k1CBIB80kETgBBeVToNb98XABeOAlQB0CST0UGZlYObmCZQiEAM1M4ADFI7zgAaxgINmTEZ1cAOnK4FLTlLKUYq3i+QREQkH8AfkQUdCw8ZUli4PLStwHhhFF08XEwgC53UFBk-Wo1MAEOOAxuzBx8FyINaj4Iii86yzieJqExKUS4I5O5M6iVdU1tXQNjU3N6q5wXyOUIACjA82IAww8wQAEpYTtejoBggwgBvB7MMD6RjUOBgUrMWj6NQwXA3FozUGgpBqNQDGBwwIYh6uOlqUpQfTYAAWoOGoIwQJ8djhohg4jhAG42URsbj8RzZQdCABfAYSZlIUUQFVqxYgUBPMAEgCM4VEACIkFaBlajHa4Fa1Fb-DrHhw+CqTXBqLtkFBwpjVc7bfMJCUiA6rRGrQArN1Rwgu2PBK05J1WzhJ0BqkWe45gH1e01gABM4W2aF22HBZoG-qwgZloAA9G3XAA9drGr1sTgwUqcNjCcHl1tGqdAA)