# Describing a 1:1 mapping between objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, mapped-types

I have logical objects with two representations, a "TypeScript representation" and a "database representation", and want to describe the mapping using some concise data structure. Here's a failing attempt, using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type Cond<T> = T extends "time" ? "time_ms" : never;

type TsDbFieldCorrespondence<
  TsType,
  DbType extends Record<Cond<unknown>, unknown>
> = {
  [P in keyof TsType]: {
    dbName: Cond<P>;
    toDb: (v: TsType[P]) => DbType[Cond<P>];
    toTs: (v: DbType[Cond<P>]) => TsType[P];
  };
};

interface TsEvent {
  time: Date;
}

interface DbEvent {
  time_ms: number;
}

const eventDescriptor: TsDbFieldCorrespondence<TsEvent, DbEvent> = {
  time: {
    dbName: "time_ms",
    toDb: (v: Date) => Number(v),
    toTs: (v: number) => new Date(v),
  },
};

// Ideally, tsc enforces that
//   1. All properties on Event are on `eventDescriptor`.
//   2. All properties of DbEvent are also accounted for on `eventDescriptor`.
```

I'm picturing this type as a building block for a system that can type-safely do forward and reverse transformations between any pair of `TsType` and `DbType`, and preferably between transforms between `Partial<TsType>` and `Partial<DbType>`, too.

---

**Questions**

Is there some twist on this that might work, or some potential enhancement to TypeScript that would facilitate such a description?

Bonus question: The above has another problem: it's asymmetric. It says "For every property of TsType, there's a corresponding property on DbType" but it doesn't also enforce that every property on DbType has a corresponding property on TsType. How could that be expressed?

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwCYB4AqA%20KBeKaoQAewEyAzlAETACWAthJVAPxW0MD6dZTAXFAggA3CACcA3AChJoSHjIARAEYAxGhAA2SeKNEQyYRElIBjCCklR5acBAA0lqMptyiJclABKEE3FGp4ZBQAVwQAawQ4AHcEDDsoUIjo2MksXABvRwBtAAUoGgQoMIgQOAAza1sAXX5MqyskJQA5AEMGfkDUHIwpeqhgOGV%20AAohfjQyFwhcqoBKHCxnWyzOlG6q3vqBiZGxpyUplaM1jDmFysgZzYBfKVvpApJRMpazeQBREQRgKDr%20%20gg-AULRIdwe3zELzeyk%20pB%20f3YEC4ZH4CGCdCUYjBkl8CDIP0RCn0JlENDAA1E40UqnUWh0egMRlM5gmsO%208RhX2AaV%20jkRtUcDWabUBbAByMoDj6AyGUFGQJBEHm2CwTXRmNEo1mUq2cB2cr2aIxYmVWEEUSciq1OuuDnukgA9A6oABJYwtDQaEDxYBkEwEBBlPxmCjAAAWIMdzqsAEYAHRQACCnqgYFEcEgolo%20igiCgbJ%20LT0ucKAANCcTSeS-KW41H6gAmBPJjSp9OZ7MUcr7AtQIvQD1kOB9ky%20UIkJBQIOiEtQcsAol%20qsU2tAA)

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640888/capturing-typescript-mapping-function-result-type-for-type-safe-mappers

Comment: Could you provide an [mcve] with some use cases, such as some specific types to plug in for `DbType` and `TsType` as well as what you expect the output would be, and how you expect to use `TsDbFieldCorrespondence`?  I'm not sure how you expect the compiler to decide which properties from `DbType` map to which properties on `TsType` without telling it, and the various possible ways you plan to actually use that type function could point to different solutions.

Comment: Thanks, @jcalz, edited. "I'm not sure how you expect the compiler to decide which properties from DbType map to which properties on TsType without telling it" In my failed attempt, I'm telling the compiler via the `dbName` string on the same object. But I think I follow why that can't work: the compiler only learns a concrete value for that when it encounters actual purported instances of `TsDbFieldCorrespondence`. Maybe if `dbName`'s type is some kind of conditional type that maps the names of corresponding fields to one another...

Comment: Does something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOaRRm) work for you?  It's quite a bit of type juggling to represent the kind of two-way mapping you're describing. I'm not worried about performance (array finds vs object lookup) or the compiler verifying that the implementation conforms to its type signature (which would be impossible for such higher order type mapping anyway). Mostly I want to be able to have the compiler verify that your mapping is complete. The `as const` on the key names might not be avoidable; you want the compiler not to forget them and widen to just `string`.

Comment: If the above works for you or gives you ideas how to proceed, I can write up an answer.  If not, please elaborate on the sticking points.  I could *probably* write up your `TsDbFieldCorrespondence<T, U>` type as something that generates a whole mess of unions for every possible pairing of `T` keys with `U` keys, but it would probably cause major issues for even modest number of keys, since the number of possible pairings grows exponentially in number of keys.

Comment: It is relatively easy to look at the object `timeDescriptor` and derive the DbType and TsType from that.  It's harder to go in the opposite direction and derive the converter from the two types.   You might need to store the key mapping as either an interface or JS object (that we can derive types from).

Comment: I'm picturing something along these lines: https://tsplay.dev/mL9y2W But I'm going to stop playing with this because it seems like @jcalz has already got it a lot further along than I have.  And there is definitely redundancy in the way I am requiring a `NameMap`.

Comment: BTW [here](https://tsplay.dev/w18pAW) is the terrible, awful, no-good version that conforms exactly to the original question, but pulling entries out of a union and pairing them up is both computationally expensive and abusing the type system.  I really hope the earlier solution [here](https://tsplay.dev/wOaRRm) is acceptable.

Comment: Will study your first solution, @jcalz, and get back in a day or two. At first glance it seems to basically work, though it errored when changing the types to `Partial<Event>` and `Partial<DbEvent>`--but I haven't spent any time understanding or debugging yet. The "spec" for that use case is that if the input has a property undefined, the output does as well. Thanks, both, for your brainpower! Very intriguing work. Will get back ASAP.